# ethereum strange error when accessing method

Tags: function, solidity, web3js

I have this very strange error that I need some help on.  I have this call from my front end:

```
    await whiskyXChange.methods.registerAsset(
      "hello", 
      123
    ).send({
      from: account[0]
    });
```

When I run this, I am getting the following error:

```
_whiskyXChange2.default.methods.registerAsset is not a function
```

My question is where is it getting _whiskyXChange2?  I don't have that anywhere in the code.  I am able to console log the interface.  I can see the registerAsset method in remix.  Can someone please give me some more ideas on how to debug this? I am on OSX, the contract is deployed to ganache 1.1.0 and the contract is compiled using solc 0.4.23.

Comment: What are you using on your front end?, metamask?, Can I see your solidity function: `registerAsset`?

Comment: Hi Marcos,  thanks for getting back. I figured it out.  It was user error mixing up the export statements.